# PHP recursive Iterator

Tags: php, recursion

I need to recursively traverse a certain directory and list all of the files inside of it I have found an example on the PHP website however after further searching I am not able to find a solution to my problem. The problem is that it prints out the entire path but I only want to echo out the first containing folder of the file. So for example as it sits now I get this output:

`/var/www/example.com/public_html/images/6.Blah/_Original/DSC_0174.jpg`

But I want it to echo:

`_Original/DSC_0174.jpg`

or

`/_Original/DSC_0174.jpg`

Here is the code I am using:

```
<?php

$path = realpath('/etc');

$objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
foreach($objects as $name => $object){
    echo "$name\n";
}

?>
```

Comment: have you tried using `basename()`?

Comment: basename only gets me the file name I need the directory that contains it plus the file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a formatting issue, you can approach it in many different ways. One way will be to split the string into an array and grab the last two elements.

```
foreach($objects as $name => $object){
    $pieces = explode("/",$name);
    $length = count($pieces);
    $result = $pieces[$length-2]."/".$pieces[$length-1];
}
```